# Single page app: Set authentication cookie without redirection

Tags: jquery, authentication, redirect, cookies

Currently working on a SPA, I would like to achieve login only through jquery - ajax.
This actually works fine, but when closing the page and then coming back to the page, i am never logged in.

This obvisouly happens because after providing credentials, there is no redirection, which I would like to avoid.

So the question is: is it possible to somehow, send the cookie from the server to the client with jquery, and from there set it in the browser, so that when the user comes back, he's still signed in?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to the question. On the server, do this:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(account.name, true);
            System.Web.HttpCookie authCookie = this.RenewCurrentUser();

private System.Web.HttpCookie RenewCurrentUser()
    {
        System.Web.HttpCookie authCookie =
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = null;
            authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

            if (authTicket != null && !authTicket.Expired)
            {
                FormsAuthenticationTicket newAuthTicket = authTicket;

                if (FormsAuthentication.SlidingExpiration)
                {
                    newAuthTicket = FormsAuthentication.RenewTicketIfOld(authTicket);
                }
                string userData = newAuthTicket.UserData;
                string[] roles = userData.Split(',');

                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User =
                    new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(new FormsIdentity(newAuthTicket), roles);
            }
        }

        return authCookie;
    }
```

Can't remember where I found this